# Google Charts: Fixing Date shown on hAxis when using ChartRangeFilter control

Tags: php, charts, google-visualization

The dates on hAxis displayed correctly as per the image shown below.

[image]

But when I adjust the control filter to a certain range, the dates start to show wrongly.

[image]

Any ways I can handle such exceptions?

**Here's a sample link for review:**
http://codepen.io/pen/bdybgj

```
 --
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because range is less then one day. If you want to do some thing different in that case then you can use listener to draw some different or hide temporarily main chart or what ever you want.
Bellow is the example of listener.

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(control, 'statechange', function (e) {

    if(!e.inProgress){

    //check difference between control.getState().range.start and control.getState().range.end
    //if difference is less than one day etc then you can do what ever you want with graph here

    }

});
```

}